# NSURLCredential not working for synchronuos request in iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone

I am using Synchronous request  and passing the credentials but I am getting authentication error in response. Below is my code of request and response from server.

Request:-

```
NSURLCredential *userCredentials = [NSURLCredential  credentialWithUser:@"username"
                                                               password:@"paswd"
                                                            persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

NSURLProtectionSpace *space = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc] initWithHost:@"http://webaddress.inc.com"
                                                                    port:80
                                                                protocol:@"http"
                                                                   realm:@"webaddress.inc.com"
                                                    authenticationMethod:nil];

[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setCredential:userCredentials
                                             forProtectionSpace:space];

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webaddress.inc.com"]
                                                          cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed
                                                      timeoutInterval:30];


NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                           returningResponse:&response
                                                       error:&error];
```

/////////// Response

401 Authorization Required

---

Note: If I am sending the request with async request it is working fine as in that case
**didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge** is giving them the required credentials when asked for.

I am sure there might be something missing in my code.

Waiting for your valuable inputs.

Comment: Hi, I know you asked this question a while back, but do you mind showing us the asynchronous request that was successful?

Comment: For aync request you get the callback - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge  . You can put your code there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever tried [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)  which makes easier http operations in IPhone enviroment. And It has really simple and good documentation. I used to use it inside of my projects, It was working awesome.

Comment: it seems it is not working on OS4
So currently I cannot go for that in my project

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to help to you about OS4